# Trigger to send Email to contacts

Tags: apex, trigger, after

I am writing a trigger to send email to all contacts of an account when it is edited.

```
trigger SendEmailToContacts on Account (after update) 
{   
 try{  
   String addresses;
    for(Account acc : Trigger.new)
        {system.debug('e2='+acc.contacts);
        system.debug('e2='+acc.contacts.size());
            for(Contact con : acc.contacts)
            {system.debug('e1='+addresses);
                if(con.email != null)
                {
                    addresses = addresses  + ':'  + con.email;
                    system.debug('e='+addresses);
               }
            }   

            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            List<String> emailAddresses = new List<String>();
            emailaddresses = addresses.split(':',0);
            message.ToAddresses = (emailaddresses);
            message.subject = 'congrats';
            message.plainTextBody = 'you a test account.';
            List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> results = Messaging.sendEmail(new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> {message});                   

          } 
    }catch(Exception ec)
           {    
              system.debug('error is' + ec);
  }
                  }
```

The control is not going in second for loop

> for(Contact con : acc.contacts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Triggers will not have information about parent or child records .You will have to explicitly query them back .

```
trigger SendEmailToContacts on Account (after update) {
 map<id,Account> accountMap = new map<id,Account>(Select Id,(Select Id,Name from Contacts) FROM Account);
try{  
  String addresses;
  for(Account acc : accountMap.values())
    {system.debug('e2='+acc.contacts);
    system.debug('e2='+acc.contacts.size());
        for(Contact con : acc.contacts)
        {system.debug('e1='+addresses);
            if(con.email != null)
            {
                addresses = addresses  + ':'  + con.email;
                system.debug('e='+addresses);
           }
        }   

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        List<String> emailAddresses = new List<String>();
        emailaddresses = addresses.split(':',0);
        message.ToAddresses = (emailaddresses);
        message.subject = 'congrats';
        message.plainTextBody = 'you a test account.';
        List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> results = Messaging.sendEmail(new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> {message});                   

      } 
}catch(Exception ec)
       {    
          system.debug('error is' + ec);
        }
 }
```

Although this is not part of this question would like to point few things that will not work for you

1.There is a chance that you will easily hit the email limits with this code .

Please try to move Messaging.sendEmail outside FOR loop

2.Always use setTargetObjectId() method of SingleEmailMessage as it avoids limits

3.Follow a trigger handler pattern and do not code anything inside trigger .Its hard to maintain and debug .

4.Lastly you do not need two FOR loops here .You can just loop over the contact records and use relationship reference back to account .

Comment: I think you mean `setTargetObjectId()` and how does this avoid limits (like the 1000 external email addresses per day limit? Am I out of date here? See [Apex Email Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_email.htm)

Comment: Please read those docs that you posted now and check for setTargetObjectId() documentation .The email that user is sending is Contact Email Id and setTargetObjectId() will avoid this :)

Comment: Mohith -- I thought about that and should run an experiment - when I read the doc link - my understanding was that only if `setTargetObjectId()` was a `User` would the limits not apply. One can send email to Contacts through the 'application' without limits applying - which I always took to mean sending via the 'send email button' or email alerts via workflow or process builder

Comment: @cropredy Experimented with the same and emails run without any limits :)

Comment: cool - I learned something :-)